# Two headings on the same row are sticked together - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

can somebody explain me, I have an issue with the CSS of bootstrap
[image]
On this page you can see the two headings h1 and h2 that are in the same row can stick together instead of taking space as a block because the row has a display:flex property. Is there any way to make these two headings on two separated line? I tried to add display:block to the two headings but that doesn't work. Thank you all!

Comment: Code must be posted as code, not image. Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Just put each of the headers into their own <row>, like so: `<div class="row"><h1>H1 text</h1></div> <div class="row"><h2>H2 text</h2></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way is to have two rows. But as you asked, you can do something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="d-block w-100">Heading 1</h1>
  <h1 class="d-block w-100">Heading 2</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add class `flex-column` to you row.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" style="background-color: red;">
  <div class="row flex-column">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```